# Telegram bot - sendMessage text

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have 2 problems with programming telegram bot by PHP.

1. problem:
   please, When I try send text with more lines by using API of telegram. By this code:

```
<?php
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, true);
$chatId= $update["message"]["from"]["id"]?$update["message"]["from"]["id"]:null;
$mess= "here is my text.";
$mess = $mess. "\n";
$mess = $mess. " this is new line".;
send($mess, $chatId);

function send($text,$chat){
   if(strpos($text, "\n")){
        $text = urlencode($text);
    }

    $parameters = array(
        "chat_id" => $chat,
        "text" => $text,
        "parse_mode" => "Markdown"
    );

    api("sendMessage?", $parameters)
}

function api($method,$command){
$token = "******";
$api = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/$method";

    if(!$curld = curl_init()){
       echo $curld; 
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $command);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $apiRequest = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close($curld);
    return $apiRequest;
}
```

My text in telegram bot look as:

"here+is+my+text.+this+is+new+line."

2. problem, maybe question:
   When user come to my telegram bot, so I want to user see keyboard's buttons, which I created. Now this I have only for new user, he must click on button "Start".
   But I want to user see keyboard's buttons, when he return sometimes.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special chars in your text are caused by the `urlencode()` call.

Since you're passing the data as **POSTFIELD**, **there's no need** to use `urlencode()`

Also, there were some syntax error's like a extra `.` behind `$mess = $mess. " this is new line".;`.

Updated script:

```php
<?php
    $update = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $update = json_decode($update, true);
    $chatId= $update["message"]["from"]["id"]?$update["message"]["from"]["id"]:null;
    $mess= "here is my text.";
    $mess = $mess. "\n";
    $mess = $mess. " this is new line";

    send($mess, $chatId);

    function send($text,$chat){

        $parameters = array(
            "chat_id" => $chat,
            "text" => $text,
            "parse_mode" => "Markdown"
        );

        api("sendMessage", $parameters);
    }

    function api($method, $command){

        $token = "!!";
        $api = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/{$method}";

        if(!$curld = curl_init()){
           echo $curld;
        }
        // curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $command);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        $apiRequest = curl_exec($curld);
        curl_close($curld);
        return $apiRequest;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh soo, I didn't realize that. The dot was there by mistake when I pasted the code here.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [westacks/telebot](https://github.com/westacks/telebot) library. This code does the same thing but with less code and more clear

```php
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

// Init bot
$bot = new TeleBot('your bot token');

// Get update from incoming POST request
$update = $bot->handleUpdate();

// Send message
$bot->sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => $update->chat()->id,
    'text' => "here is my text.\n this is new line",
    "parse_mode" => "Markdown"
]);
```